# Сохранить значения TextBox во время привязки к коллекции

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в c# winforms vs2010 решить следующую задачу:
Есть код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

            persons.Add(new Person { Name = "ФИО1" });
            persons.Add(new Person { Name = "ФИО2" });
            persons.Add(new Person { Name = "ФИО3" });

            var listBox = ((ListBox)CheckedListBox1);
            listBox.DataSource = persons;
            listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

            //Привязка текстбоксов к коллекции:
            TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value1");
            TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value2");
            TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value3");
}

public class Person
    {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string Value1 { get; set; }
            public string Value2 { get; set; }
            public string Value3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Перед событием "button1_Click" в текстбоксах "TextBox1,TextBox2,TextBox3" есть текст, который после выполнения этого события очищается. Вопрос: как сохранить существующий текст в текстбоксах сразу после привязки либо после привязки вернуть текст. В дальнейшем пользователь может менять значения в текстбоксах, но это уже после привязки. Нужно только один раз, т.е. сразу после привязки, вернуть имеющейся текст.

Answer (score 1):

Перед привязкой элементов прочитайте содержимое ваших текстбоксов в объект `Person`, добавьте его в коллекцию `persons`, а затем выполните привязку.

---

1. Если вам точно нужна привязка именно *коллекции* к вашим текстбоксам, то код выше будет привязывать поля `Value1`, `Value2` и `Value3` из *первого* элемента коллекции.
2. Если вы решили воспользоваться именно привязкой данных, тогда привяжите ваши данные к контролам сразу, в конструкторе формы или в событие `OnLoad`. Так как при повторном нажатии на кнопку вы получите исключение о повторной привязке к свойству.
3. Все общение со значениями контролов должно происходить через привязанную модель. В вашем случае через объекты `Person`. Другими словами, сперва вы привязываете данные контролам, а потом изменяете данные в этих контролах.

Сделал для вас иллюстрирущий код, как привязывается коллекция к набору контролов для вашего случая. Надеюсь, это поможет вам разобраться:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly List<Person> _persons = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Value1 = "1_Value1", Value2 = "1_Value2", Value3 = "1_Value3" },
        new Person { Value1 = "2_Value1", Value2 = "2_Value2", Value3 = "2_Value3" },
        new Person { Value1 = "3_Value1", Value2 = "3_Value2", Value3 = "3_Value3" }
    };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindData();
    }

    private void BindData()   
    {   
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _persons, "Value1");
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", _persons, "Value2");
        textBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", _persons, "Value3");
    }

    private void ForwardButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        BindingContext[_persons].Position++;
    }

    private void BackwardButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingContext[_persons].Position--;
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, можете привести пример кода?

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, код: List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
            foreach (object item in CheckedListBox1.Items)
            {
                Person p = new Person();
                p.Name = item.ToString();
                p.Value1 = TextBox1.Text;
                persons.Add(p);
            }
            var listBox = ((ListBox)CheckedListBox1);
            listBox.DataSource = persons;
            listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
            TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", persons, "Value1"); - для одного текстбокс верен?,если в CheckedListBox1 уже есть строки

Comment: Спасибо большое!